# How to test database connection through JDBC

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I got a problem about testing db connection. It was a handed over Java application in Eclipse. (which I am not familiar with it).

The app used JDBC to connect with Oracle and put the db information inside the context.xml. I tried to add different `System.out.println()` in the `DBconn.java`, but didn't show any log in console window. Any suggestion to me for testing the connection?

Comment: What better way to test the connection other than running a simple query with it?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't see output from `System.out.println()`? Or that you want to check the database connection? I prefer to configure a validationQuery with a server-provided connection pool and not worry about the rest.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger?